# Tic Tac Toe : Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, 2d

I'm really lost, I'm having trouble building this game. I need your guys help. Been struggling for days now to figure this out. I have three classes, Driver, Board, and Player. I have the driver, and I think the board class under control. I'm mainly struggling with the player class. The goal of this is to have a computer player be able to randomly input into the array, and then have the player be able to input their choice of where they want to play.

```
public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //new tic-tac-toe board
        Board board = new Board();

        //two new players (conputer and human)
        Player computer = new Player(board, "X");   //Give computer player access to board and assign as X.
        Player human = new Player(board, "O");      //Give human player access to board and assign as O.
        board.print();
        computer.computerMove();

        //while the game is not over
        while(!board.gameOver())
        {
            //let computer move first
            computer.computerMove();

            //print tic-tac-toe board
            board.print();

            //if the game is not over yet
            if (!board.gameOver())
            {
                //let the human make a move
                human.humanMove();

                //if the game is over
                if (board.gameOver())
                {
                    //print the board
                    board.print();
                }
            }
        } 

        //print out the winner (if there is one) of the game
        board.printWinner();
    }
}
```

Board class

```
public class Board
{
    private String player = "X";
    private String cpu = "O";
    int row = 3;
    int column = 3;
    private String[][] theBoard = new String[row][column] ;

    public Board()
    {
        theBoard = theBoard;
    }

    public boolean gameOver()
    { 
       if  (theBoard[0][0] == player && theBoard[0][1] == player && theBoard[0][2] == player || // 1st row
            theBoard[1][0] == player && theBoard[1][1] == player && theBoard[1][2] == player || // 2nd row
            theBoard[2][0] == player && theBoard[2][1] == player && theBoard[2][2] == player || // 3rd row
            theBoard[0][0] == player && theBoard[1][0] == player && theBoard[2][0] == player || // 1st col.
            theBoard[0][1] == player && theBoard[1][1] == player && theBoard[2][1] == player || // 2nd col.
            theBoard[0][2] == player && theBoard[1][2] == player && theBoard[2][2] == player || // 3rd col.
            theBoard[0][0] == player && theBoard[1][1] == player && theBoard[2][2] == player || // Diagonal          \ 
            theBoard[2][0] == player && theBoard[1][1] == player && theBoard[0][2] == player) //   Diagonal      /
            {
                return false;
            }
        else if (theBoard[0][0] == cpu && theBoard[0][1] == cpu && theBoard[0][2] == cpu || // 1st row
            theBoard[1][0] == cpu && theBoard[1][1] == cpu && theBoard[1][2] == cpu || // 2nd row
            theBoard[2][0] == cpu && theBoard[2][1] == cpu && theBoard[2][2] == cpu || // 3rd row
            theBoard[0][0] == cpu && theBoard[1][0] == cpu && theBoard[2][0] == cpu || // 1st col.
            theBoard[0][1] == cpu && theBoard[1][1] == cpu && theBoard[2][1] == cpu || // 2nd col.
            theBoard[0][2] == cpu && theBoard[1][2] == cpu && theBoard[2][2] == cpu || // 3rd col.
            theBoard[0][0] == cpu && theBoard[1][1] == cpu && theBoard[2][2] == cpu || // Diagonal          \ 
            theBoard[2][0] == cpu && theBoard[1][1] == cpu && theBoard[0][2] == cpu) //   Diagonal      /

            {
                return false;
            }
       else{

           return true;
        }
    }

    public void print()
    {

        System.out.println(theBoard[0][0] + " | " + theBoard[0][1]+ " | " + theBoard[0][2] + "\n----------");

        System.out.println(theBoard[1][0] + " | " + theBoard[1][1]+ " | " + theBoard[1][2] + "\n----------");

        System.out.println(theBoard[2][0] + " | " + theBoard[2][1]+ " | " + theBoard[2][2] + "\n");

    }

    public void printWinner()
    {
       if  (theBoard[0][0] == player && theBoard[0][1] == player && theBoard[0][2] == player || // 1st row
            theBoard[1][0] == player && theBoard[1][1] == player && theBoard[1][2] == player || // 2nd row
            theBoard[2][0] == player && theBoard[2][1] == player && theBoard[2][2] == player || // 3rd row
            theBoard[0][0] == player && theBoard[1][0] == player && theBoard[2][0] == player || // 1st col.
            theBoard[0][1] == player && theBoard[1][1] == player && theBoard[2][1] == player || // 2nd col.
            theBoard[0][2] == player && theBoard[1][2] == player && theBoard[2][2] == player || // 3rd col.
            theBoard[0][0] == player && theBoard[1][1] == player && theBoard[2][2] == player || // Diagonal          \ 
            theBoard[2][0] == player && theBoard[1][1] == player && theBoard[0][2] == player) //   Diagonal      /
            {
                System.out.println("X - won!");
            }
        else if (theBoard[0][0] == cpu && theBoard[0][1] == cpu && theBoard[0][2] == cpu || // 1st row
            theBoard[1][0] == cpu && theBoard[1][1] == cpu && theBoard[1][2] == cpu || // 2nd row
            theBoard[2][0] == cpu && theBoard[2][1] == cpu && theBoard[2][2] == cpu || // 3rd row
            theBoard[0][0] == cpu && theBoard[1][0] == cpu && theBoard[2][0] == cpu || // 1st col.
            theBoard[0][1] == cpu && theBoard[1][1] == cpu && theBoard[2][1] == cpu || // 2nd col.
            theBoard[0][2] == cpu && theBoard[1][2] == cpu && theBoard[2][2] == cpu || // 3rd col.
            theBoard[0][0] == cpu && theBoard[1][1] == cpu && theBoard[2][2] == cpu || // Diagonal          \ 
            theBoard[2][0] == cpu && theBoard[1][1] == cpu && theBoard[0][2] == cpu) //   Diagonal      /

            {
                System.out.println("O - won!");
            }


    }
}
```

And Player class, this is the one I'm struggling with the most.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Player

{
    String player = "X";
    String cpu = "O";
    private Board ticTac;
    public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public Player(Board board, String inBoard )
    {
        ticTac = board;
    }
public void randomPlace()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {

            }
        }
    }
    public void computerMove()
    {


    }        

    public void humanMove()
    {

    }
}
```

prints

```
null | null | null
----------
null | null | null
----------
null | null | null
```

Comment: You asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446884/random-position-in-string-array-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe this can help you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Player

{
    String player = "X";
    String cpu = "O";

    int row = 3;
    int column = 3;

    private Board ticTac;


    public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public Player(Board board, String inBoard )
    {
        //here you have the board in player
        tictac = board;
    }

    public void computerMove()
    {   //here you can code something like this
        tictac.put(tictac.getRandomFreePlace(),cpu);
    }        

    public void humanMove(Position position)
    {
        tictac.put(position, human);
    }
}
```

you have to code in Board the put(Position, String), and the getRandomFreePlace()

Then scan for player movement and print the board.

-------------UPDATE--------------

Oh, you want to initialize your board? you can make that with a double for

```
  for(i=0;i<row;i++){
       for(j=0;j<column;j++){
        //here you can set the value you want
        theBoard[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: saying that Board (capital B) cannot be  converted to java.lang.String[][]. Thanks for trying though I DO appreciate any ideas.

Comment: thank you, but do you think I could do it without editing Driver?

Comment: OH nvm I see what you did ;)

Comment: Yes, you can, I only changed the humanMove, but you can use it without parameters and ask the player movement inside it.

Comment: Thanks for the help I think my main confusion was getting ticTac to be used for board. Im new to 2d arrays.

Comment: Another question is, when i run it It is making every spot in the array "Null" can i get rid of this somehow?

Comment: @pewpew I see you are using java but you are not programming like a OOP should be. You repeat a lot of code in the board with the ifs, maybe you can fix that with some "for" and extracting a method like isPlayer(position) and isComputer(position). Don't forget to set your question as solved if you could finish your code ^^

Comment: @pewpew Uhm... i'm not sure what you say, can you update the post with your new code? :)

Comment: I figured I would start making another method for generating random location.

Comment: There you have how to initialize your board with values.

Comment: So i put it into the board class constructor, except that my Array is a String array, so instead of 0 i put it as " ".

Comment: yes, if you want, it's better if you put it in a "void intilializeBoard()" and then in the constructor call the method.

Comment: You are helping me so much, can i give you bonus points? haha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93897/discussion-between-leoxs-and-pewpew).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understood your question can you re-word it or give me an example?

From what i understood is that you would like to have your board method used in your player class is that correct?

if you created a board class and gave it whatever characteristics it need then inside your player class you can created a new class of "it" and then call it by its name to retrieve whatever characteristics you gave it.